# PHP Service Account Accessing a Google Calendar

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I was having trouble trying to list all the events of a specific Google Calender using PHP. I was wondering if I could see a working example?
I've looked at documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#examples), but it isn't working for me. If someone could give a working example of a **service account** listing the events of a certain calender, that would be awesome!

Comment: check this link http://www.spunmonkey.com/display-contents-google-calendar-php/ . What is your issue with google calendar? Are you not able to retrieve all the events which are in your calendar? Are you getting any error while retreiving? You can try your request here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list. Please post your code and error if you have any?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm using the first link and inputting both my API key and my Calendar ID. When I include the php file, my page doesn't load.

Comment: Oh, it fixed. Instead of using an imported calendar, I had to use a personal calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link spunmonkey.com/display-contents-google-calendar-php . What is your issue with google calendar? Are you not able to retrieve all the events which are in your calendar? Are you getting any error while retreiving? You can try your request here developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/…. Please post your code and error if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.spunmonkey.com/display-contents-google-calendar-php/) for a guide, but make sure to share your calendar first!
All credit goes to SGC.